# How can i start with Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I am new in Windows Workflow Foundation.Please give some basic idea for understanding Windows Workflow Foundation correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend reading through some of the material on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328, if you prefer books (paper or kindle) then Apress and Sams (Wrox current offering is a little old, but very likely due for an update RSN) have books for beginners and pros.